# `readlink` not returning absolute path when used with script located in folder known to `PATH`

Tags: bash, path, readlink

Having a hard time understanding why `readlink` seems to be dependent from where it is called from rather than supplying an actual path when used with custom scripts.

### Environment

**WSL** Ubuntu 20 on Windows 11

### Steps to reproduce

1. Navigate to a folder listed in `PATH`, e.g. `/usr/local/bin`
2. Create a new file `linktest` which contains this code:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
echo $(readlink -f $1)
```

3. Save it and give it executable permissions via `sudo chmod +x linktest`
4. Create an arbitrary file like `demo.txt` in the same folder
5. Call `linktest demo.txt`, output will be `/usr/local/bin/demo.txt`
6. Navigate to any other folder like `/home/<user>`
7. Call `linktest demo.txt` again, output will be `/home/<user>/demo.txt` instead of `/usr/local/bin/demo.txt`

Apart from the fact that `/home/<user>/demo.txt` does not actually exist, I wonder why `readlink` behaves relative instead of absolute. How can I get the actual, absolute path independent from the origin of the call?

Comment: `readlink` behaves neither absolute nor relative, and what you are seeing is completely unrelated to where your `linktest` script. Instead, the question is what `readlink` uses as the base directory for resolving the filename. And (consistent with pretty much *every other command*) it resolves it relative to the *current working directory*. Doing anything else wouldn’t make much sense. That being said, what you actually seem to want is to find the path of the currently running script. And getting this in a platform-independent way that correctly works in all scenarios is surprisingly hard.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/59895/1968, but beware that many of the answers there are outright wrong.

Comment: `readlink()` just returns the text of the symbolic link target. When the OS follows a symlink it interprets it relative to the containing directory, but that doesn't automatically propogate to other uses.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Thanks for the information. This explains why I couldn't find anything useful, as I was asking the wrong question. Hopefully others asking the same will be redirected.

Comment: Assume you have two files `/home/user/demo.txt` and `/usr/local/bin/demo.txt`. You write the script as written in your question call it as `scriptname demo.txt`. You do this from `/home/user/`, `/usr/local/bin` and `/random/directory/`. Ask yourself now the question: How would my program know which file to pick.

Comment: Replace `echo $(readlink -f $1)` with `readlink -f "$1"` to avoid problems with spaces and other special chars.